# MPI send in passing pointer pointer c + +

Tags: c++, mpi, send

```
MPI_Send (&t[0], 2, MPI_INT, 1, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

I can not get the address of this pointer pointer in the slave,A is a matrix already allocated ** A,A[0] is the address of the first row of the matrix

```
// MASTER

int** T = new int*[2];
T[0] = A[0];

MPI_Send(&T[0], 2, MPI_INT, 1, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

// SLAVE

int **V = new int*[2];
MPI_Recv(V, 2, MPI_INT, 0, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

int resposta = 1;

MPI_Send(&resposta, 1, MPI_INT, 0, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dereference the pointer so you are left with an object of type `int*`:

```
MPI_Recv(*V, ...);
```

or use

```
MPI_Recv(&V[0][0], ...);
```

Comment: I need to pass a pointer to a pointer, and not integer pointer.

Comment: int ** V * = new int [2];
V [0] = pointer paw want to save a whole, I can not get this structure in the slave.

Comment: @MaxmilianFerreiradeLemos A pointer to pointer would be `V`, a pointer would be `*V`. `MPI_Recv` recieves a pointer, so that is why you should pass `*V` or `&V[0][0]`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to pass a structure by send?

EX:
struct {
int task;
int * row_a;
int * row_b;
Aux};

Comment: @MaxmilianFerreiradeLemos I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: because I have to pass a row of a matrix and a column of another matrix, the only way is with two SEND? (matrix multiplication)

Comment: @MaxmilianFerreiradeLemos By SEND are you referring to the function `MPI_SEND`?

Comment: MPI_SEND yes, so I thought a structure

Comment: I'm not familiar with MPI so I wouldn't know, sorry.

Comment: Okay, you've helped me a lot.